# How do I add two WHERE in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, where-in

```
SELECT ID_worker, Name_worker, salary+500,
FROM Supermarket
WHERE ID_worker IN ("2","4");
```

The above query works, as it adds 500 to the salary of workers whose ID is either 2 or 4. The problem is that only the workers with the ID 2 and 4 appear. I want all of them to appear even the ones whose salary remains the same. How do I do that?

Comment: `+ case when id in (2,4) then 500 else 0 end` and remove `where` clause at all

Comment: WHERE is a filter on which rows are returned.  It doesn't apply any logic to the data.

Comment: Whats with the double quotes? (`""`), and there is an additional comma (`,`).

Comment: @DaleK i cant find that option sorry. if you want to remove the question i no longer need help thanks

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to do this, but the most straightforward is to use a case conditional and completely remove the select's where condition, for example:

```
select 
  ID_worker, 
  Name_worker, 
  case when ID_worker in ('2','4') then salary+500 else salary end, 
from Supermarket
```